# webscraping an .ASPX site with Selenium and/or Scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to Python/Selenium and coded the following in python /Windows to scrape the 5484 physician demo's in the, [MA-Board of Reg. Website](http://profiles.ehs.state.ma.us/Profiles/Pages/ChooseAPhysician.aspx?Page=1).

**My Issue:** The website is .aspx, so I initially chose Selenium. However, would really appreciate any insights/recommendations on coding the next steps (see below).  More specifically, if it is more efficient to continue with selenium or incorporate scrapy?  Any insights are greatly appreciated!:

1. Select each physician's hyperlink (1-10 per page) by clicking each hyperlinked "PhysicianProfile.aspx?PhysicianID=XXXX" on the "ChooseAPhysician page".
2. Follow each, and Extract the, "Demographic info"
   Demographic info: "phy_name", "lic_issue_date", prim_worksetting, etc
3. Return to, "ChooseAPhysician page", click "Next"
4. Repeat for additional 5474 physician

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

   driver = webdriver.Chrome()                         driver.get('http://profiles.ehs.state.ma.us/Profiles/Pages/ChooseAPhysician.aspx?Page=1')

   #Locate the elements
   zip = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtZip\"]")
   select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cmbDistance\"]"))
   print select.options
   print [o.text for o in select.options]
   select.select_by_visible_text("15")
   prim_care_chekbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_SpecialtyGroupsCheckbox_6\"]")
   find_phy_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSearch\"]")


   #Input zipcode, check "primary care box", and click "find phy" button
   zip.send_keys("02109")
   prim_care_chekbox.click()
   find_phy_button.click()

   #wait for "ChooseAPhysician" page to open
   wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

   open_phy_bio = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"PhysicianSearchResultGrid\"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a")
   element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_selected(open_phy_bio))
   open_phy_bio.click()

   links = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"PhysicianSearchResultGrid\"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a")
   for link in links:
       link = link.get_attribute("href")
       self.driver.get(link)

   def parse(self, response):
   item = SummaryItem()
   sel = self.selenium
   sel.open(response.url)
   time.sleep(4) 
   item["phy_name"] = driver.find_elements_by_xpaths("//*[@id=\"content\"]/center/p[1]").extract() 
   item["lic_status"] = driver.find_elements_by_xpaths("//*[@id=\"content\"]/center/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a[1]").extract()
   item["lic_issue_date"] = driver.find.elements_by_xpaths("//*[@id=\"content\"]/center/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]").extract()
   item["prim_worksetting"] = driver.find.elements_by_xpaths("//*[@id=\"content\"]/center/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]").extract()
   item["npi"] = driver.find_elements_by_xpaths("//*[@id=\"content\"]/center/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]").extract()
   item["Med_sch_grad_date"] = driver.find_elements_by_xpaths("//*[@id=\"content\"]/center/table[3]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]").extract()
   item["Area_of_speciality"] = driver.find_elements_by_xpaths("//*[@id=\"content\"]/center/table[4]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]").extract()
   item["link"] =  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"PhysicianSearchResultGrid\"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a").extract()


   return item
   ```

Comment: `selenium` and browser interactions would always be a bottleneck in a setup  with scrapy and to make it more efficient you need to avoid using `selenium`, or, at least use it as less as possible.

Comment: I imagine it has to do with selenium's required wait-times as well?  Selenium's install was a rigmarole, so forsee additional issues.  Any good, python scraping .ASPX, resources you can recommend ? Thanks in advance ! @alecxe

Comment: @EricJohn give a try with Scrapy a python framework (https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html)

Comment: I reviewed your recommended Scrapy link, and many others to reformat my code, however, receive the following error: "TypeError: 'Rule' object is not iterable" Here is a link to my updated question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28710392/typeerror-rule-object-is-not-iterable-webscraping-a-aspx-page-in-python . Again, any assistance is greatly appreciated ! Thanks again !