# "TypeError: 'Rule' object is not iterable" webscraping an .aspx page in python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, web-crawler

I am using the following code to scrape this website (http://profiles.ehs.state.ma.us/Profiles/Pages/ChooseAPhysician.aspx?Page=1) ; however, obtain the following TypeError:

"File "C:\Users\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\contrib\spiders\crawl.py", line 83, in _compile_rules
    self._rules = [copy.copy(r) for r in self.rules]
TypeError: 'Rule' object is not iterable"

I don't have any code  written on line 83, thus, wondering if anyone has ideas on how to resolve the issue? I'm using Python 2.7 in Windows.

Thanks!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class MdiMassSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "MdiMass"
    allowed_domains = ["http://profiles.ehs.state.ma.us/Profiles/Pages/FindAPhysician.aspx"]
    start_urls = ["http://profiles.ehs.state.ma.us/Profiles/Pages/ChooseAPhysician.aspx?Page=1"]
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(".*http://profiles.ehs.state.ma.us/Profiles/Pages/PhysicianProfile.aspx?PhysicianID=.*,"))),)
    # all pages to scrape follow the same: http://profiles.ehs.state.ma.us/Profiles/Pages/PhysicianProfile.aspx?PhysicianID=1311
    #PhysicianID=XXXX

    def __init__(self):
        CrawlSpider.__init__(self)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    #def __del__(self):
    #   self.selenium.quit()
    #   print self.verificationErrors

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get('http://profiles.ehs.state.ma.us/Profiles/Pages/ChooseAPhysician.aspx?Page=1')


    def parse(self):
        select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cmbDistance\"]"))
        print select.options
        print [o.text for o in select.options]
        select.select_by_visible_text("15")

        zip = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtZip\"]")
        zip.send_keys("02109")

        prim_care_chekbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_SpecialtyGroupsCheckbox_6\"]")
        prim_care_chekbox.click()

        find_phy_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSearch\"]")
        find_phy_button.click()

        for sel in response.xpath("//*[@id=\"PhysicianSearchResultGrid\"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a"):
            item = MdiMassItem()
            item["phy_name"] = sel.xpaths("//*[@id=\"content\"]/center/p[1]").extract() 
            item["lic_status"] = driver.find_elements_by_xpaths("//*[@id=\"content\"]/center/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a[1]").extract()
            item["lic_issue_date"] = driver.find.elements_by_xpaths("//*[@id=\"content\"]/center/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]").extract()
            item["prim_worksetting"] = driver.find.elements_by_xpaths("//*[@id=\"content\"]/center/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]").extract()
            item["npi"] = driver.find_elements_by_xpaths("//*[@id=\"content\"]/center/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]").extract()
            item["Med_sch_grad_date"] = driver.find_elements_by_xpaths("//*[@id=\"content\"]/center/table[3]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]").extract()
            item["Area_of_speciality"] = driver.find_elements_by_xpaths("//*[@id=\"content\"]/center/table[4]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]").extract()
            item["link"] =  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"PhysicianSearchResultGrid\"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a").extract()
            print item
```

**Edited Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class MdiMassSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "MdiMass"
    allowed_domains = ["http://profiles.ehs.state.ma.us/Profiles/Pages/FindAPhysician.aspx"]
    start_urls = ["http://profiles.ehs.state.ma.us/Profiles/Pages/ChooseAPhysician.aspx?Page=1"]

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(".*http://profiles.ehs.state.ma.us/Profiles/Pages/PhysicianProfile.aspx?PhysicianID=.*"))),)
    # all pages to scrape follow the same: http://profiles.ehs.state.ma.us/Profiles/Pages/PhysicianProfile.aspx?PhysicianID=1311
    #PhysicianID=XXXX

    def __init__(self):
        CrawlSpider.__init__(self)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get('http://profiles.ehs.state.ma.us/Profiles/Pages/ChooseAPhysician.aspx?Page=1')

    def parse(self, response):
        driver = self.driver
        select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cmbDistance\"]"))
        print select.options
        print [o.text for o in select.options]
        select.select_by_visible_text("15")

        zip = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtZip\"]")
        zip.send_keys("02109")

        prim_care_chekbox = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_SpecialtyGroupsCheckbox_6\"]")
        prim_care_chekbox.click()

        find_phy_button = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSearch\"]")
        find_phy_button.click()

        for sel in response.xpath("//*[@id=\"PhysicianSearchResultGrid\"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a"):
            item = MdiMassItem()
            item["phy_name"] = sel.xpaths("//*[@id=\"content\"]/center/p[1]").extract() 
            item["lic_status"] = driver.find_elements_by_xpaths("//*[@id=\"content\"]/center/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a[1]").extract()
            item["lic_issue_date"] = driver.find.elements_by_xpaths("//*[@id=\"content\"]/center/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]").extract()
            item["prim_worksetting"] = driver.find.elements_by_xpaths("//*[@id=\"content\"]/center/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]").extract()
            item["npi"] = driver.find_elements_by_xpaths("//*[@id=\"content\"]/center/table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]").extract()
            item["Med_sch_grad_date"] = driver.find_elements_by_xpaths("//*[@id=\"content\"]/center/table[3]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]").extract()
            item["Area_of_speciality"] = driver.find_elements_by_xpaths("//*[@id=\"content\"]/center/table[4]/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]").extract()
            item["link"] =  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"PhysicianSearchResultGrid\"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a").extract()
            print item
```

**Python Log Message:**

```
C:\Users\Anaconda2\MdiMass>scrapy crawl MdiMass -o items.csv
2015-02-26 01:11:47-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.4 started (bot: MdiMass)
2015-02-26 01:11:47-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto
2015-02-26 01:11:47-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'MdiMass.spiders', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'SPIDER_M
ODULES': ['MdiMass.spiders'], 'FEED_URI': 'items.csv', 'BOT_NAME': 'MdiMass'}
2015-02-26 01:11:47-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: FeedExporter, LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStat
s, SpiderState
2015-02-26 01:11:49-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMidd
leware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMidd
leware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-02-26 01:11:49-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLe
ngthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
C:\Users\Anaconda2\MdiMass
2015-02-26 01:11:49-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: CsvWriterPipeline
2015-02-26 01:11:49-0500 [MdiMass] INFO: Spider opened
2015-02-26 01:11:49-0500 [MdiMass] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-02-26 01:11:49-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-02-26 01:11:49-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080
2015-02-26 01:11:49-0500 [MdiMass] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://profiles.ehs.state.ma.us/Profiles/Pages/FindAPhysician.as
px> from <GET http://profiles.ehs.state.ma.us/Profiles/Pages/ChooseAPhysician.aspx?Page=1>
2015-02-26 01:11:49-0500 [MdiMass] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://profiles.ehs.state.ma.us/Profiles/Pages/FindAPhysician.aspx> (re
ferer: None)
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x0493B210>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at
0x0493B0B0>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x0493B1F0>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElemen
t object at 0x0493B110>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x0493B150>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webeleme
nt.WebElement object at 0x0493B170>]
[u'', u'5', u'10', u'15', u'30', u'50']
2015-02-26 01:11:50-0500 [MdiMass] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-02-26 01:11:50-0500 [MdiMass] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
        {'downloader/request_bytes': 575,
         'downloader/request_count': 2,
         'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
         'downloader/response_bytes': 19312,
         'downloader/response_count': 2,
         'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
         'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,
         'finish_reason': 'finished',
         'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 26, 6, 11, 50, 150000),
         'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
         'log_count/INFO': 7,
         'response_received_count': 1,
         'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
         'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
         'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
         'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
         'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 26, 6, 11, 49, 134000)}
2015-02-26 01:11:50-0500 [MdiMass] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Why 2 definitions of parse ? could you move the self.driver.get in the init ?

Comment: Good question & suggestion ! Making those changes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the following line.

```
rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor (allow=(" 
.*http://profiles.ehs.state.ma.us/Profiles/Pages/PhysicianProfile.aspx?PhysicianID=.*,"
))))
```

You miss positioned a comma. The correct code is:

```
rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=("
.*http://profiles.ehs.state.ma.us/Profiles/Pages/PhysicianProfile.aspx?PhysicianID=.*"
))),)
```

By this correction you make the rule iterable.

Good definition of iterators here: ([Build a Basic Python Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151/build-a-basic-python-iterator/24377#24377))

Iterator objects in python conform to the iterator protocol, which basically means they provide two methods: `__iter__()` and  `next()`.

The `__iter__` returns the iterator object and is implicitly called at the start of loops.

The `next()` method returns the next value and is implicitly called at each loop increment.
`next()` raises a StopIteration exception when there are no more value to return, which is implicitly captured by looping constructs to stop iterating.

Comment: Thanks for the fix idea and comprehensive explanation! I made the change (saved the change), re-ran the code, but I'm still receiving the following error.  I even tried # off the " rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(".*http://....))),)" and still receiving the following. Any ideas?:  C:\Users\Anaconda2\MdiMass>scrapy crawl MdiMass
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
  "File "C:\Users\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\contrib\spiders\crawl.py", line 83, in _compi
le_rules
    self._rules = [copy.copy(r) for r in self.rules]
TypeError: 'Rule' object is not iterable

Comment: The code in the answer was obviously tested. I will make a double check about your error message

Comment: Update: You were correct abt. the, "rule=...))),)." edit. It solved the, "TypeError!" Thanks! I had to restart, but now receiving a different error (regarding pipelines):       File "C:\Users\Anaconda2\MdiMass\MdiMass\pipelines.py", line 15
    self.csvwriter.writerow([item['phy_name'][0], item['lic_status'][0], item['lic_issue_date'][0], item['prim_worksetting'][0], ite
m['npi'][0], item['Med_sch_grad_date'][0], item['Area_of_speciality'][0], item['link'][0])

                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @ EricJohn Since the answer fix your problem please accept it. About your new errors the data you shared are not enough to understand what it is happening. The error could be in the item definition or in the xpath used

Comment: @aberana - Of course, and I would Upvote per your assistance, but I lack the requisite, "15 rep. points."  Again, thanks for the assistance! I debugged the "line 15 SyntaxError", (edited my code) and the crawler opens /inputs correct page info; however,  doesnt crawl the page per the following error:   File "C:\Users\Anaconda2\MdiMass\MdiMass\spiders\MdiMass_spider.py", line 17
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(".*http://profiles.ehs.state.ma.us/Profiles/Pages/PhysicianProfile.aspx?PhysicianID=.*,")), f
ollow=True) callback='parse_item',)

                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: please double check the commas again. in the solution i wrote down there was no come inside the allow xpath but only at the end after the parse item

Comment: Thanks again! I made the comma correction/update to the rules, and the code ran (i.e. selenium opened the 1st page. Input the zipcode, clicked the "primary care" button, clicked drop down, and clicked to advance to the second page (http://profiles.ehs.state.ma.us/Profiles/Pages/ChooseAPhysician.aspx?Page=1); however, stalls there.  Assume it's either a xpath code issue, or systemic .aspx issue.  Again, really appreciate the assistance!

Comment: as a methodological approach I would suggest you to give a good clean up to the code re test every thing and in case of need submit a new question here on SO. You have made so many updates to the code that at the moment it would be quite hard even to understand what is the right code to start from.

Comment: aberna - Thanks again, and I am reviewing my code and reviewing  Scrapy/Selenium tutorials to find the specific issues / solutions.  Thanks again!